# How to calculate an integral with an unknown number of integration variables?

Tags: integration, multiple-integral, maximum-likelihood, log-likelihood

How to calculate the following integral, which has an unknown number of integration variables?
$$
\int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\cdots\int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\exp\left[-\dfrac{1}{2\theta}\sum_{i=1}^n\big(b_i-\sum_{j=1}^ma_{ij}x_j\big)^2-\dfrac{1}{2(1-\theta)}\sum_{j=1}^mx_j^2\right]dx_1,\dots,dx_m
$$
where $\theta\in(0,1)\ \text{and}\ a_{ij},b_i,x_j\in(-\infty,+\infty)$.

Comment: Not unknown, there are $m$ of them.

Comment: @Aruralreader So, how to describe, a fixed but "unobserved" number? An $m$ number of integration variables or?

Comment: Thanks @woody but calling bs on this now until you say what 'unobserved' means to you. Yet good luck in your further endeavors!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\int_{R^m}e^{-\frac{1}{2}x^T\Sigma^{-1}x+\langle s, x \rangle }dx=(\sqrt{2\pi})^m e^{\frac{1}{2}s^T\Sigma s}.$$ Apply this to

$$\Sigma^{-1}=\frac{1}{1-\theta}I_m+\frac{1}{\theta}A^TA, \ \ \ s=\frac{1}{\theta}A^Tb.$$

Comment: Thank you so much! Could you write some key steps in deriving $\int_{R^m}e^{-\frac{1}{2}x^T\Sigma^{-1}x+\langle s, x \rangle }dx=(\sqrt{2\pi})^m e^{\frac{1}{2}s^T\Sigma s}$? Could you give me a webpage or some keywords about dealing with an integral like $\int_{R^m}f(x)dx$?

Comment: If $\Sigma$ is diagonal the formula reduces to a product of ordinary one dimensional integral. If not, write $\Sigma=U^TDU$ with $D$ diagonal and $U$ orthogonal and do the change of variables $y=Ux$. Since $|\det U|=1$ we have $dx=dy$ and we land on $$\int_{R^m}e^{-\frac{1}{2}y^TD^{-1}y+\langle Us, y \rangle }dy=(\sqrt{2\pi})^m e^{\frac{1}{2}sU^TD Us}.$$